# Graph weighted averages in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm doing an analysis of the Current Population Survey. I have a wage variable (wage), a time-series variable (qtr), and an observational weight (pworwgt). Each quarter has thousands of observations.

I can easily make a table showing the weighted average wage in each quarter:

```
table qtr [iw=pworwgt], contents(mean wage)
```

What I want to do, however, is graph this easily within Stata. I tried to use egen to make a variable containing the mean by qtr, but egen mean() does not allow for weights.

Comment: It may be easy just to use `egen`'s `total()` function to get the numerator and denominator of a weighted average, and then divide. There is a user-written `egen` function for this purpose, but doing it from first principles should be easy and instructive. Or even easier is to use `collapse` to get a reduced dataset of averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways this can be done is with a regression followed by two margins* commands:

```
webuse hanley
table rating [iw=pop], contents(mean disease)
reg disease i.rating [iw=pop]
margins rating
marginsplot, noci
```

This has the advantage of not altering your data in any way.

Comment: Not the quickest solution in the world, but it works and allows me not to collapse the data. Thanks!